# Erro selecionar texto com o mouse, Formulários dentro de tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

Encontrei uma solução elegante em como trabalhar com MDI Tabbed Interface, estou criando em tempo de execução um tabcontrol dentro do meu form MDI, e estou criando uma nova aba para cada formulário. da forma citada abaixo !

```
form.TopLevel = false;
superTabControlPanel.Controls.Add(form);
form.Show();
form.BringToFront();
```

Porém já rodei toda a internet e tentei vários posts e nenhum deu realmente certo, o Formulário é adicionado corretamente, porem ao tentar selecionar algum texto dentro de um textbox usando o mouse, simplesmente não da certo, eu só consigo selecionar texto se eu retirar as bordas do formulário, e eu não queria fazer isso, agradeço desde já !

Comment: Já tentou utilizar *form.Activate()*?

Comment: opa, sim ja tentei e infelizmente também nao ajudou em nada, provavelmente tem a ver com o TopLevel = False, a solução acho que seria implementar algumas API's mas eu nao sei quais usar.